# Geodesics of low regularity

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesic, connections

Section 3.6 of Kobayashi and Nomizu's "Foundations of differential geometry, volume 1" says "A curve $\tau=x_t$, $a<t<b$, where $-\infty\leq a<b\leq\infty$, of class $C^1$ in a manifold $M$ with a linear connection is called a geodesic if the vector field $X=\dot{x}_t$ defined along $\tau$ is parallel along $\tau$, that is, if $\nabla_XX$ exists and equals 0 for all $t$, where $\dot{x}_t$ denotes the vector tangent to $\tau$ at $x_t.$"

I am aware that it is possible to define weak solutions of differential equations, and that there is research interest in considering geodesics of low regularity. However, how does Kobayashi and Nomizu's definition make sense with respect to the classical definitions? In such a setting, doesn't consideration of $\nabla_XX$ require the curve to be at least $C^2$, rather than $C^1$?

Comment: Note that a geodesic being $C^2$ is in a sense a consequence and not an assumption. A curve $x(t)$ is a geodesic with respect to an affine connection, if it satisfies something like $$\ddot{x}^i + \Gamma^i_{jk}\dot{x}^j\dot{x}^k = 0.$$ If you assume that Christoffel symbols are $C^0$ and $\dot{x} \in L^2$, then the second term lies in $L^1$ and the first term is a distribution. The equation then immediately implies that $\ddot{x}$ is $L^1$, which implies $\dot{x}$ is continuous, which implies that $\ddot{x}$ is continuous (using the equation), which implies the curve is $C^2$.

Comment: Things get interesting only if the regularity of the connection is weakened. In that situation, most work is done on length spaces, where the connection is ill-defined but geodesics are defined to be locally length-minimizing.

Comment: I believe the same kind of reasoning applies even if the Christoffel symbols are only bounded and measurable! Anyway, now it seems to me that even in the classical context, $x\in C^1$ makes sense, since then $x'$ is a continuous vector field along $x$, and it is meaningful to say that, for any $s$ and $t$, the parallel transport of the vector $x'(t)$ along $x$ equals the vector $x'(s)$. (Nonetheless it is not a priori meaningful to refer to $\nabla_{x'}x'$.) Would you agree with this?

Comment: Hi to @Deane :) I was on your side, Quarto. I don't think K/N had any of this regularity stuff in their heads; it's certainly not the style of their book. Anyhow, I think your final statements are right.

Comment: Hey, @TedShifrin! @QuartoBendir, I'm a bit confused by what you're saying. Doesn't what I say include your case? $x$ being $C^1$ implies that $\dot{x}$ is $L^2$. Or am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: And I don't see how to work with curves, if the Christoffel symbols are only bounded and measurable. Isn't it possible that the Christoffel symbols aren't even well-defined along the curve?

Comment: My interest was just in the (somewhat artificial) question of understanding Kobayashi & Nomizu's definition by only using material from Kobayashi & Nomizu's book, in particular without reference to distributions or $L^p$ spaces. I agree that your explanation is good and more general. (You are also correct, in talking even more generally I should have said that the assumption is that the functions $\Gamma_{jk}^i\circ x$ are bounded and measurable.)